# Firebase analytics does not allow comparing by app version

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

In the past I was able to add a comparison in Firebase Analytics based on my app version. It stopped working a couple of months ago. I'm having the same problem in multiple apps one of which has not been updated. This is obviously very important information. You want to see how a new version is doing compared to the one it's replacing. Especially while doing a staged roll out on the Play Store.

This is the message I get in the Build comparison view.
"No data currently available for this dimension"

Does anyone know the cause?

Comment: Same for my app also.  Any workaround you got?